# get degrees from ratio via tan

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, angle

I want to get an angle in degrees of a triangle, in JS.

How can I get out the degrees of the angle with Tangent after calculating opposite / adjacent?

[image: Formula for TAN]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
degrees = Math.atan(a/b) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Be certain to validate b... bad things may happen if it is 0.

References: [Math.atan](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan.asp), [Math.PI](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_math.asp)

Comment: @poppel:  You may also want to look at Math.atan2 (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan2.asp)

Comment: @lolol: If you edit as you have done, you remove the links I originally embedded to the Math.atan function and Math.PI constant and you have code that is not something which can be dropped into a JavaScript program.  If you are going to edit this, please take care when doing so to ensure you're not breaking something, as you have now done twice.